# MaskedPassword.js: How to get actual value (plain text) in JS

Tags: javascript, html, maskedpassword.js

I'm using **MaskedPassword.js** to mask a password field in my form as demonstrated below:

```
<input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" autocomplete="off">
<script type="text/javascript">     
    new MaskedPassword(document.getElementById("pwd"), '\u25CF');   
</script>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the plain text value of this password field using Javascript but unable to do so.
I've already tried the following:

```
document.getElementById("pwd").value
document.getElementById("pwd").text
document.getElementById("pwd").defaultValue
document.getElementById("pwd").innerHTML
```

Can anyone help me get the actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a couple of hours, I finally found out the following fix that worked for me:

```
document.getElementById('pwd')._realfield.value
```

Posting it here might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a version of the code in [this post](https://www.sitepoint.com/better-passwords-1-the-masked-password-field/) (possibly [this implementation](https://github.com/sarahgoldman/masked-password)), I believe you would find it in the hidden field that is generated by the code, like so:

```
document.getElementById('pwd-unmasked').value
```

Comment: Hey thanks Spiny. But this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry to hear it. Do you have an url where I can find this MaskedPassword.js project?

Comment: No sorry. I don't have any such URL.